# jQuery Animation Images

Tags: jquery, css, animation, background-image, panels

I've been developing a front end and basically there's a feature I can't figure it out how to do it.

I have 2 background images and on each image I have a button. When I click on the button the opposite image animate to out off the screen. I'm doing this with jquery and the animation is working correctly. However I've troubles with the image resize. When I resize the window the right image stays above the left image and I don't want that.
Here is a link of what i'm trying to do.
http://franciscowanzeller.com/animation-example/panel.html

Any suggestions? Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

can you apply `width` of that both div left and right when screen resize. like

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
     var w = ($(window).width())/2;   //half width of window
     $( "div .left" ).css({width : w+'px'});
     $( "div .right" ).css({width : w+'px'});
});
```